Как однозначно читать формулы нормальным русским языком?
Вопрос
Как с помощью привычных языковых средств русского языка однозначно прочитать формулу?
Меня интересует формулы логики предикатов, но в принципе вопрос может быть обобщён для любой формулы где есть скобки и бинарные отношения. Это может быть и формула арифметики, думаю принцип будет тот же.
Введение.
Может показаться, что вопрос не о русском языке. Я же считаю, что он затрагивает саму суть русского языка. Я считаю, что главное для чего он нужен это для передачи сложно-орнанизованной информации. Оно в свою очередь нужно чтобы производить сложные продукты, чтобы не жить как племена в Африке. Я считаю, что информация, которой мы обмениваемся достаточно сложно организована. Суть вопроса в передачи по средствам русского языка награмождений бинарных отношений. Я решил представить вопрос в виде baby example, маленького и очень приметивного примера который должен раскрыть суть этой темы.
Актуальность.
Я умею писать доказательства по теории множеств, однако я не могу рассуждать о них в слух. Вот допустим я хочу порассуждать с помощью теории множеств о Сантабарбаре, о том кто там настоящий отец одного из героев.
Проблема в вопроссе.
Как языковыми средствами русского языка прочитать дробление текста на заголовки и подзаголовки. Надо чтобы это звучало как обычный текст.
Моя попытка.
С начала я думал, что для этого стоит сделать отдельный формальный язык. Потом решил, что неплохо было-бы это попробовать на русском.
Я понял, что можно использовать подход близкий к подходу Питера Чена или Хартмана в их статьях об eer модели. Там они с помощью обычного английского языка описывают базы данных. Самое главное, они там аггрегацию отношений отображают как сложное прдложение с слвом "который", "где" итп.
То есть (2+2)+4 можно прочитать как  2 плюс 2, где сума суммирунтся с 4.
Для начала я составил семантическое дерево для формул логики предикатов. Затем разбил его на отношения. Далее эти отношения надо представить как текст напоминающий xml, то есть разбитый на заголовки.
Примеры:

(2-2)-(3-((2-3)+2)).
Отнимаются две разности.
Где левая часть разности это разность между 2 и 2.
Где правая часть разности между 3 и суммой.
Где2 сумма между разностью и 2.
Где3 разность между 2 и 3.
(x)[(Ey)((A(x,y)->B(x,y))->(Ey)(A(x->y)->C(x,y)))]
Импликция универсальна по x.
Где левая часть импликации экзистенция от y к импликации.
Где2 импликация от от A к B.
Где3 A от x к y.
Где3 B от x к y.
Где правая часть импликации экзистенция от y к импликации.
Где2 импликация от A к C.
Где3 А от x к у.
Где3 B от x к y.

Здесь я обозначил "где1", "где2" "где3" обобщённые "где". Здесь цифра добавляется, если "где" относиться к предложению уже содержащиму где.
P.S.:
Меня интересует больше то, как это сделать на нормальном русском языке, а не на том его варианте который исспользуют математики.
Меня также не интересует насколько "грамматически правильным" будет текст, главное чтобы оно было понятным и однозначным.

Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он не имеет отношения к русскому.

А зачем нужен русския язык вообще? Он нужен чтобы что-бы что-то производить, что-то делать. Художественная литература это хорошо конечно, но от нее не так много пользы как от математики. Я считаю, что вопросс затрагивает самую суть того зачем нужен русский язык.

Я бы мог обобщить вопросс на более привычные вопроссы. Суть вопросса о том, что есть груда связанных соподчинённых отношений. Для адекватного их представление это всё надо разбить на подчинённые заголовки, подзаголовки итп. Что-то вдоде xml. Вопросс как это читать. Кажнться что такая структура данных далека от привычной. Так вот я считаю, что скорее что подобную информацию мы часто предаём текстом, только мы используем другие языковые средства. Я вот занимаюсь наукой, и часто сталкиваюсь с вопроссами о том как это адекватно рассказать на русском или английском. Вот об этом вопросс.

Пожалуйста, посмотрите информацию о том, как надо задавать вопросы на сайте.  Вопросы должны быть конкретными,  а ваш вопрос общего характера. Кроме того, ваш вопрос касается специальных разделов математики, и семантическую правильность прочтения сложных формул скорее нужно обсуждать на этом ресурсе.  Мы же можем проверить текст на предмет грамматики и стилистики. Приносите готовый текст конкретной записи.
